# Facebook OG Debugger bugged?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-4

I build my website using Laravel 4.
In the code of my pages, i sometimes use '@include('path/to/i.e./form')'.

But, when i enter the url of a webpage which has the '@include', it gives me a 'error' (Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.)

even though it displays my og stuff correct,i can't see what is still need to be debugged. I can only see it when i remove the @include.

My question is, is it possible to fix this? i.e. is there an alternative in Laravel for @include? Is there something i have to write so it will read the page correctly? And, do any others have this?

Comment: What code you use server-side should not really matter, as long as it delivers the correct results to a requesting client … Apart from that, there is too little info here to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CBroe. It all delivers the correct results, so nothing wrong server side. 

I'm sorry there is so little info, i did not know what would be needed and what wouldn't. What sort of info would be needed? i.e. from my model to controller to view to OGdebugger or .. ?

Comment: Well if you say it solely depends on your use of `@include`, and that works fine in a common browser, but not for Facebook’s scraper – then maybe your server _is_ reacting differently based on what kind of request headers it receives or something … so to implement some kind of logging to be able to compare those between a “normal” request and one from FB would be my first step in trying to debug this …